# LINQ / XML - Storing child nodes which have different names in a custom class

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Example Of Data:

```
<property>
  <price>2080000</price>
  <country>France</country>
  <currency>euro</currency>
  <locations>
    <location_9>Ski</location_9>
    <location_16>50km or less to airport</location_16>
    <location_17>0-2KM to amenities</location_17>
  </locations>
  <secondaryproptypes>
    <secondaryproptypes_1>Holiday Home</secondaryproptypes_1>
  </secondaryproptypes>
  <features>
    <features_30>Woodburner(s)</features_30>
    <features_9>Private parking</features_9>
    <features_23>Mountain view</features_23>
    <features_2>Mains Drains</features_2>
</features>
```

Example Of Property Class:

```
public class Property
    {
        public decimal price { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public string currency { get; set; }

        public List<Location> locations { get; set; }
    }
```

Example of Locations Class:

```
public class Location
    {
        public string location { get; set; }
    }
```

Main Code: (Also tried many derivatives, but this is how it stands when I gave up)

```
public void LoadXMLURL()
    {
        XDocument document = XDocument.Load("file.xml"); 

        var properties = (from p in document.Root.Elements("property")
                          select new Property
                          {

                              price = Convert.ToDecimal(p.Element("price").Value),
                              country = p.Element("country").Value,
                              currency = p.Element("currency").Value,
                              locations = new List<Location>(from l in p.Descendants("location")
                                                             select new Location
                                                             {
                                                                 location = (string)l
                                                             })
                          }

                              ).ToList();
```

I did try a number of ways of storing the list of location data nodes. Such as arrays and other lists.

Now I think my main issue is that because the nodes are varying;
"location_9"
"location_16"

I cannot specify the nodes to look at, as strictly as I could with the previous nodes.

Comment: Instead of `<location_9>` use something like `<location id="9">`

Comment: I have no control over the format of the XML, sorry I should have specified this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nice thing is that the nodes you're grabbing are grouped together in the `<locations>` element, so you can use `p.Element("locations").Elements()` rather than `p.Desendants("location")`.

Here's some code that works in LINQPad:

```
void Main()
{
    var str = @"
    <root>
    <property>
    <price>2080000</price>
    <country>France</country>
    <currency>euro</currency>
    <locations>
        <location_9>Ski</location_9>
        <location_16>50km or less to airport</location_16>
        <location_17>0-2KM to amenities</location_17>
    </locations>
    <secondaryproptypes>
        <secondaryproptypes_1>Holiday Home</secondaryproptypes_1>
    </secondaryproptypes>
    <features>
        <features_30>Woodburner(s)</features_30>
        <features_9>Private parking</features_9>
        <features_23>Mountain view</features_23>
        <features_2>Mains Drains</features_2>
    </features></property>
    </root>";
    var document = XDocument.Parse(str);
    var properties = 
        (from p in document.Root.Elements("property")
                    select new Property
                    {

                        price = Convert.ToDecimal(p.Element("price").Value),
                        country = p.Element("country").Value,
                        currency = p.Element("currency").Value,
                        locations = new List<Location>(from l in p.Element("locations").Elements()
                                                    select new Location
                                                    {
                                                        location = (string)l
                                                    })
                    }

                        ).ToList()
                        .Dump();
}

public class Property
{
    public decimal price { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }

public List<Location> locations { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public string location { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please can you expand on your answer, giving specifics of how to implement this with the Location class I have created.
Your suggestion has been one of the many I have historically tried, I'm sure my mistake is simple. So seeing a full example would really help me.

Thanks

Comment: @Birksy89: I pasted a working example. The only changes I made were to  add a root element and close the property tag on the sample text, use Parse instead of Load, and change the code the way I described in my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

Once one has the parent, just generically ask for the children via `Elements`. Here is an example

```
locations = p.Descendants("locations")
             .Elements()
             .Select (elm => new Location()
                               {
                                  location = elm.Value
                               } );
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer got me the closest.

Although, I had to change my Property class to the following;
 `public IEnumerable<Location> locations { get; set; }`

Rather than a list, as I couldn't figure out how to cast it correctly